# Get prettier to uglify certain json files

Tags: prettier

We're using prettier to format code and this plugs into a pre commit hook.

I want it to do that, but for certain json files, I'd like it to minify the json instead. I can do that externally, but well I would rather have something that's already plugged in.

```
{
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "src/**/*.json",
      "options": {
        "parser": "json-stringify"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": "src/path/to/folder/**/*.json",
      "options": {
        "parser": "json-minify"// Some parser perhaps?
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: For what programming language / environment?

Comment: typescript. It should minify json files thoguh